# Accessing custom attribute DescriptionAttribute on RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've added a DescriptionAttribute on the RouteAttribute in my API solution with the hopes that I can retrieve the information programmatically as part of Controller function.  For example:

```
[Route("api/users/{filter}"), Description("Search for users that match {filter}")]
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to access it however.  I have looked at several posts in SO that provide guidance but I am unsure how to use those with a RouteAttribute.

Using Visual Studio debug I was able to drill into the RouteAttribute entry and see the value:

> (new
>   System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView((new
>   System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(((System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)((System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor[])(new
>   System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryValueCollectionDebugView(item.Route.DataTokens.Values).Items[0]))[0]).MethodInfo.CustomAttributes).Items[1]).ConstructorArguments).Items[0]).Value

Unfortunately this is inaccessible due to it's protection level.  Is there a way to get to this information?

Comment: Your description attribute isn't "on the route attribute" it's on your controller class (or whatever specific method the attributes are applied to). Combining attributes the way you did is just a shorter notation for `[AttributeA()] [AttributeB()]`

Comment: Does that mean it's not an accessible value for my purposes?